# Unable to cast System.string to System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

For some reason, i have been struggling with this since yesterday to generate an image from a Base64 string, it just wouldnt and it shows ok  from a test box but does not create the image file , be it PNG or JPG hence i decided to paste here maybe i am wrong somehow.

Code looks like this

```
public void generateImageFromBase64(int idnumber)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-FJBB72F\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ImageControl;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();

    string query = "select img from PDFImgTableB where id =@id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idnumber);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        //byte[] imgData = (byte[])rd[0];
        **byte[] fileData = (byte[])rd.GetValue(0);
        string img = Convert.ToString(fileData);**
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
        using (var imageFile = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\output\test.png", FileMode.Create))
        {
            imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            imageFile.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the winform i am using to call it to generate the image file, looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ReadAndConverttoJPG.ReadFileDB drd = new ReadAndConverttoJPG.ReadFileDB();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                drd.generateImageFromBase64(2);
                MessageBox.Show("OK!");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: "+ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What could i be missing here ?

**Edit**

Now here is what, Klaus, it does not seem to output the PNG image to my desktop folder unlike the PDF which did earlier

Code now looks like this

```
public void generateImageFromBase64(int idnumber)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-FJBB72F\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ImageControl;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();

    string query = "select img from PDFImgTableB2 where id =@id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idnumber);
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        string imgBase64 = rd.GetString(0);
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\output\test.png", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DbDataReader` has many other methods to return typed(!) data such as `GetBytes()` which you may find useful.  But it does seem like a Base64 string would be saved as string...

Comment: try removing `ImageFile.Flush()` and adding `ImageFile.Save();`

Comment: What's the type of img in the database? Is it stored as base64 string or as binary data?

Comment: Show us how you save that img in database in the first place, it seems that converting that byte array to string is unnecessary here.

Comment: @KlausGütter base64 string

Comment: Are  you sure there is a row in the table with the given ID? Use the debugger to step through your function and see if you actually reach the line fs.Write(...).

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. As should the final FileStream, which then won't need a Close. And you may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

Since the database field contains the base64 string, simply get it as string and convert to binary:

```
string imgBase64 = rd.GetString(0);
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBase64);
```

Comment: would this work especially when saving as nvarchar(max) on mssql

Comment: i have updated the question as it does not seem to output the file to the directory @Klaus